# Reduce memory usage

Tags: unity, firefox, browser, memory-usage

I have just installed the standard default desktop configuration of Ubuntu 12.10 (Quantal Quetzal). My PC only has 1GB of RAM and is struggling a little. What steps can I take to reduce the memory overhead of the standard install? If it makes a difference, I use Firefox, and a terminal most of the time.

Simply running those two applications I see:

```
free -m
            total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached

Mem:           938        873         64          0          5      167
-/+ buffers/cache:        701        237
Swap:          959        158        801
```

Comment: Do a ps -e to see how many processes are running. Although with that amount of memory I recommend xubuntu. Normally I recommend at least 2GB for Ubuntu to run with a couple of other apps with no problems. With 1GB I would recommend more xubuntu for it. If you still want to run Ubuntu it can be lowered to at least 500MB in some cases.

Comment: The first thing that I can tell you is, **no more Firefox**. This web browser have a big memory consume. Instead of this one, you can use **Chromium** (of the popular ones) or Midori. In the Software-Center you can find a couples of browsers with little consume.

Comment: Am more with Lucio. Using another browser like Midori will help a lot. Using it with Xubuntu will help even more.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Answer (score 5):

You can easily install and try out different desktop environments (instead of the default, Unity). Once installed, you can switch between different desktop environments at the log-in screen (there is an icon near your name, which, when clicked, allows you to select).[image]

Probably in your case, with 1GB ram, I would suggest the lubuntu desktop (based on LXDE). To install, open a terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

If you don't want the whole environment, you can install LXDE by itself

```
sudo apt-get install lxde
```

Most everything will be the same but you'll have a new look that is less memory intensive (see many screenshots [HERE](http://www.howtogeek.com/107368/how-to-install-the-lightweight-lxde-desktop-on-ubuntu/)). Firefox will be there, and the terminal will look a little different.

If you don't like the LXDE look, you can read about other desktop environments [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available). Options include Xfce (Xubuntu) and KDE (Kubuntu).

Comment: @Flintoff, To put my 2 cents in I found that e17 (from enlightenment.org) is the most resource friendly desktop environment, You can try the Bodhi Linux ubuntu distro that uses e17. I thing the project is great, the speed and customization of e17 is great. But the looks and feels is different, you need to get use to it, I like it but I cannot use it daily, and still prefer Unity.

Comment: is this advice still valid for 20.04?

Comment: Seems the answer is Yes - here's an overview of downstream distros for 20.04.  https://linuxconfig.org/the-8-best-ubuntu-desktop-environments-20-04-focal-fossa-linux

Answer (score 2):

## The web Browser

**Firefox**

**Firefox** is the default web browser of Ubuntu. It is a great browser but is not recommended for computers with minimal resources, since this has a large memory consumption. See Firefox working in my system:

[image: firefox_mem_usage]

**Epiphany**

I recommend to you the [**Epiphany** Browser](http://www.gnome.org/projects/epiphany/) (now simply called as *Web*). You will be surprised at how well it works, it fulfills the promise to be *lightly*. The size of the download is only of **2Mb**! As the [Epiphany's homepage](http://projects.gnome.org/epiphany/) say: it is *Simple, beautiful, and easy to use.*

[image: screenshoot]

**Others**

In the [Software Center](http://apps.ubuntu.com) you will find great Web Browsers that are *lightly*, *faster*, and *smaller*.