# Firefox is pounding my system what should I do

Tags: firefox, performance

I'm running the latest version of firefox 17.0.1 on ubuntu 12.10 on a Acer Aspire One 722 Netbook. It has an amd dual core C60 processor and 2GB RAM.

[image: Output from top]

As you can see, firefox is absolutely killing my system, it responds really slowly and opening tabs is a royal pain. I have on an average 4-5 open tabs at a given time. Is there something that I can do to make my browsing experience more zippy?

Additionally I run the following addons

1. Firebug
2. HTTPS Everywhere
3. Ad block plus

Comment: What do you see with Firebug disabled? You can put that information in your question.

Comment: Firebug is disabled only right now.

Comment: please disable your other addons as well and see if it makes any difference.  Otherwise, everyone will blame the add-ons. :)

Comment: Sadly the memory usage is kind of normal with Firefox. No idea about the CPU usage though.

Comment: possible duplicated: http://askubuntu.com/q/133737/62483

Comment: You can review [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/224793/62483) with options concerning to your problem.

Comment: You have this problem as soon as you open Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that something in your browser profile is causing the problem.  One possible solution is to use the fairly new "reset firefox" process, which will create a new firefox profile for you with most of your settings preserved.

**Warning**: not all settings will be preserved, read the link below carefully first!

- At the top of the Firefox window, click the Help menu and select Troubleshooting Information.
- Click the Reset Firefox button in the upper-right corner of the Troubleshooting Information page.
- To continue, click Reset Firefox in the confirmation window that opens.
- Firefox will close and be reset. When it's done, a window will list the information that was imported. Click Finish and Firefox will open. That's it – you're done!

More information:

http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-firefox-easily-fix-most-problems#os=linux&browser=fx17

Answer (score 1):

It is a pretty well known fact Firefox is not the lightest browser in terms of system resources.

You had a few options in my opinion on different browsers to use.

I personally use the offical Google Chrome because it comes bundled with its own version of Flash that always works so no fuss.  It also has it's own version of a pdf reader.

https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/

We also have Midori which is a light browser, but I haven't used it extensively so can't tell you what it is like.

http://twotoasts.de/index.php/midori/

Comment: I have taken you advice and installed chrome, it seems to be better in terms of performance right now.

I think I 'll come back to firefox after a couple of releases. I like it a lot but lets see.